# C# LINQ to select all the properties from the list and adding one additional property without having to create new strongly typed class

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
var people = new[]
        {
           new {Id = 6000, Name = "Jennifer", Age = 21}, 
           new {Id = 6001, Name = "Alton", Age = 15},
           new {Id = 6003, Name = "Milford", Age = 23}
        };
```

Wants result :

```
{ Id = 6000, Name = Jennifer, Age = 21 , Is Minor = false }
{ Id = 6001, Name = Alton, Age = 15, Is Minor = true }
{ Id = 6003, Name = Milford, Age = 23, Is Minor = false }
```

Add additional property is Minor without creating the new class for returning the result``

Comment: This is not possible with anonymous types (`new { ... }`), because they're immutable. Create a mutable type with the property that's to be initialized later or use value tuples if you want to avoid heap allocations.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Select` method from LINQ like this:

```
var people = new[]
{
    new { Id = 6000, Name = "Jennifer", Age = 21 },
    new { Id = 6001, Name = "Alton", Age = 15 },
    new { Id = 6003, Name = "Milford", Age = 23 }
};

var peopleWithIsMinor = people.Select(person => new
{
    person.Id,
    person.Name,
    person.Age,
    IsMinor = person.Age < 18
});
```

Comment: I don't want to specify property names except the new or additional ones. I wanted all the properties from that list without manually specifying those. e.g. .select(item=> new{*, isMinor}); // something like this

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to create a new strongly typed class then using an anonymous class (like in your example) is likely your best option.

```
var result = people.Select(person => new
{
  person.Id,
  person.Name,
  person.Age,
  IsMinor = GetIsMinor(person)
});
```

I am assuming that you can determine the value of the additional property based on the existing properties.

Comment: I don't want to specify property names except the new or additional ones. I wanted all the properties from that list without manually specifying those. e.g. .select(item=> new{*, isMinor}); // something like this

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you are looking for ?

```
var result = people.Select(item => new
{
     Id = item.Id,
     Name = item.Name,
     Age = item.Age,
     IsMinor = item.Age < 18
}).ToList();
```

Comment: @BaumTheFelJoy 

I don't want to specify property names except the new or additional ones.

I wanted all the properties from that list without manually specifying those.

e.g. .select(item=> new{*, isMinor}); // something like this